# Only one thread works while running multithreaded program (with threads inside thread)

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm facing a problem running my multithreaded application. Let me explain. I have a for loop which create n threads and these n threads create again a couple of 2 threads for each of them.
So finally I have 2*n threads which have to run in the same time.

I can see in my program that n couple of threads are created, but after the creation of the n threads only the first couple is working. The last n-1 other couple of threads do nothing.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
void *thread1_send (void * arg_threads)
{  
    // do some work

    pthread_exit (0);
}

void *thread2_listen (void * arg_threads)
{
    // do some work

    pthread_exit (0);
}


void *thread_multi (void * arg_threads)
{
    // first thread
    if (pthread_create (&th1, NULL, thread1_send, arg_threads) < 0) {   
        printf ("Error pthread_create for thread 1\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    //second thread
    if (pthread_create (&th2, NULL, thread2_listen, arg_threads) < 0) {   
        printf ("Error pthread_create for thread 2\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    (void)pthread_join (th1, &ret_t);
    (void)pthread_join (th2, &ret_t);

    pthread_exit(0);
} 



pthread_t * th_multi = (pthread_t *) malloc( n * sizeof(*th_multi) );
....
....
// for loop in a function
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{                                                                              
    // creation of n threads
    if (pthread_create (&th_multi[i], NULL, thread_multi, arg_threads) < 0) {   
        printf ("Error pthread_create for thread_multi [%d].\n", i);
        exit (1);
    }

    pthread_exit(0); // it's unclear for me what pthread_exit is doing here.

} // end of for
```

Comment: The pthread_exit() at the bottom can go away... does your main thread ever do a pthread_join() on the threads it created?  If not, the shutdown code that runs after main() returns may be cleaning up resources the threads are using before those threads are done using them.

Comment: I'm not doing any pthread_join() for the threads created in the loop. If needed where I need them? Inside or outside the loop? And also for the pthread_exit() if I put it outside the loop I take the focus on the last thread created. Normally the program have to keep going until I stop it. That means threads don't need to end for me. They send and listen messages in while(1). So would I really need to join them even if I never returning from the main?

Comment: pthread_join() will block until the specified thread exits.  Putting pthread_join() inside the loop would therefore block the main thread from launching the second child thread until after the first thread exits, which is presumably not what you want.  So you should have a second loop after your first loop that calls pthread_join() on each spawned child thread.  If your child threads never exit, then this second loop will block inside its first call to pthread_join() indefinitely, which is sufficient -- but if/when you decide to allow your program to shutdown, this will allow a clean shutdown.

Comment: So I removed the pthread_exit() in the loop and add a second loop for joining as suggested, but now this is only the last thread who's working while the n-1 first couple of threads do nothing. So where's the problem? From the work that thread 1 and thread 2 are doing ? Thread priorities/synchronization? Reentrancy?

Comment: Hard to say.  What I'd do is sprinkle printf's everywhere to find out where each thread is blocked, or if it has exited, or was never started, or what.  (You can do a printf("%i: at line %s:%i\n", (int) pthread_self(), \_\_FILE\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_); to get output that shows which thread is executing at which line when).

Comment: So after using printf, it turns out to be that the (n-1) first threads, the ones which are supposed to send data, never wake up after a sleep() that I use in my code. While the (n-1) listening threads of the couple is working but receive nothing. I can see that only the last thread wake up after its sleep() and keep running.

Can't we use sleep() in multitreaded program ? Is there other alternatives I can use ?

Comment: It's okay to use sleep() in a multithreaded program.  You might check what argument you are passing in to sleep(), though.